# Disable notification popup when resuming activity on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, notifications, notification-area

Under Windows 11 (I guess the same applies to Windows 10 too, as the notification system is pretty similar on theese two) there is a notification system which enables popups when an event is happening. And this is useful for email clients such as Thunderbird or other.

Now, theese popups seems to "freeze in time" when I am not using my computer. It keeps accumulating them but not displaying them. Instead, when the PC senses that I'm back (eg I start moving my mouse, the screen is reenabled etc), it starts slooowly popping them up one by one.

Sometimes there is a LOT of notifications which are collected that way. And their slow popping is really annoying, as all this time a zone of my screen is effectively obscured and I tend to click on theese notifications instead of whatever I'm trying to do. Even closing one of them just shows the next in line instead of stopping this behaviour, which frustrates even more. It seems like briefly opening the notification area alleviates this issue, but it is still frustrating.

Now, I know how to disable the popups alltogether for a select application, but theese popups are actually pretty useful in normal usage, so I don't want to disable them alltogether. It is only this "freeze in time" and popping up after restarting the PC usage which is unwanted.

Now, is there any way to disable that annoying behaviour? Make the notification area ignore the fact that I'm away from the PC and prevent it "collecting" theese notifications?

Comment: You can disable notifications on lock screen, and set Notification Priority to  ‘Top’, ‘High’, or ‘Normal’, so only some override an app. This site shows other settings, too:  https://allthings.how/how-to-manage-notifications-in-windows-11/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'm not talking about the lock screen. I'm talking about the default desktop. My computer doesn't autolock after an idle period.